# Why doesn't php's imap_open() like SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, imap

Might not be a very helpful question, but I can't image there isn't a clear answer to this problem. I just figured out via some already answered questions about `imap_open()` connection problems, that when connecting to an SSL server the function will most likely return an error. So I was just wondering, what the problem is for PHP to use SSL?

Using this connection string returns error:

```
function connect($host, $port, $login, $pass){

    $this->server = $host;
    $this->username = $login;

    $this->link = imap_open("{". $host .":". $port."}INBOX", $login, $pass);
        if($this->link) {
            $this->status = 'Connected';
    } else {
        $this->error[] = imap_last_error();
        $this->status = 'Not connected';
    }
}
```

While this one connects without issues:

```
function connect($host, $port, $login, $pass){

    $this->server = $host;
    $this->username = $login;

    $this->link = imap_open("{". $host .":". $port."/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $login, $pass);
        if($this->link) {
            $this->status = 'Connected';
    } else {
        $this->error[] = imap_last_error();
        $this->status = 'Not connected';
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears most people do not have their local root certificate store set up properly (seems PHP doesn't ship with this configured correctly), so when it attempts to validate the remote certificate (a necessary part of the security) it can't.   Using novalidate-cert leaves you open to attacks.   Also, many small installations are using self-signed (invalid) certs.

Answer (score 2):

If the server requires an encrypted connection, it means you are connecting to an encrypted port, and your script will fail if you don't use `/ssl` (won't connect at all).

The server may also accept a plaintext connection and then require encryption (see [STARTTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS)), but I guess it would connect and then send a IMAP error.

This can be checked by the port you are connecting and your mail server specification. Usually ports 465/993 are assigned to use encrypted TLS/SSL connections, while 25/143/587 may accept an unencrypted connection and then ask for an upgrade.